# How to load CSS on PC and Mobile by jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 2 CSS files:

- **data.css** for PC
- **mobile.css** for Mobile

How to load **data.css** on PC and **mobile.css** on Mobile by using jQuery?

Comment: You could do this without jquery and use @media in css instead, check out http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: I won't do it in jquery if I were you. You can do it in full CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Use this to detect `agent`:*

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
$('link[rel="stylesheet"]').attr('href','mobile.css');
} else {
$('link[rel="stylesheet"]').attr('href','data.css');
}
```

*or detect `window width`:*

```
if ($(window).width() < 960) {
   $('link[rel="stylesheet"]').attr('href','mobile.css');
}
else {
   $('link[rel="stylesheet"]').attr('href','data.css');
}
```

*if you have more than one `stylesheet`, you can set an `ID` for it:*

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="myStyle" type="text/css" href="path/to/file">
```

**JS:**

```
$('#myStyle').attr('href','mobile.css');
```

Comment: @PrajwalCPradeep if this solved your problem, please accept the answer and vote up. Your welcome.

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice post on what exactly you need, please have a look.

https://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/

Answer (score 0):

You have to check for screen size using "window", like below

```
if ( $(window).width() > 739) {     
  //Add your css file for large screens here
}
else {
  //Add your css file for small screens here
}
```

**Note :** change width value(739) according to your needs.

But I recommend you to **write media queries instead of having two different files**.